# Only allow one Checkbox to be Selected In LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I know radio buttons are ideal for this but  everyone wants checkboxes.

In this case I have two checkboxes in my markup and if one is selected I want to make sure the other is not.  The code in my JS below seems to be doing what I want. At least from the console. But the view is not getting updated.

Do I need to do this with a trackable property?

```
    setBoxes(event){
        let boxes = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input');
        let currentBox = event.target.name;
        console.log(currentBox);
        console.log(Array.from(boxes));
        const boxArray = Array.from(boxes);
        console.log(boxArray)
        for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
            let box = boxes[i];
            console.log(box.name);
            console.log(box.checked);
            if (box.name !== currentBox && box.checked){
                box.checked === false;
                console.log(box.checked);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
            box.checked === false;
```

`===` is "exact comparison". You want to use the assignment operator (`=`):

```
            box.checked = false;
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I can't believe it was that simple.

Answer (score 5):

The issue was actually found by **@sfdcfox**. But If you want to allow only `1` checkbox to be checked and the rest `N-1` checkboxes to be automatically unchecked you can simplify and replace the whole code by the next two lines:

```js
// onclick event handler
setBoxes(event){
    const boxes = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input');
    boxes.forEach(box => box.checked = event.target.name === box.name);
}
```

Comment: That is great. I thought I had to turn the node list into an array. Is your arrow function working based on the truthy values in JS?

Comment: Well. That's just an example. The point is that there must be some unique attribute value for every checkbox (whether it is `name` or `data-id`) and its type is always of `string`. Even if you have a checkbox with `name=0 | true | false | null | so on` attribute value, so this value will be of `string` type and the comparison logic will work correctly. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefname

Answer (score -1):

**JavaScript**

```js
// this.records property having all wire functions data.
// Onchange function from checkbox input
checkboxOnChange(event){
    this.records.forEach((res, index) => {
        if(res.Id == event.target.dataset.id){
            res.Custom_Active__c = event.target.checked;
        } else {
            res.Custom_Active__c = false;
        } 
    });
    console.log(this.records);
}
```

```html
<lightning-input type="checkbox" data-id={index} onchange={handleCheckboxChange} name="addPrimary" checked={acc.Custom_Active__c}></lightning-input>
```

Comment: <lightning-input type="checkbox" data-id={index} onchange={handleCheckboxChange} name="addPrimary" checked={acc.Custom_Active__c} ></lightning-input>

Comment: I've downvoted this because this is mostly a code dump (the explanation is as important as the solution itself), and it doesn't really "fit" with the code that OP currently has (i.e. OP is using a selector to grab the elements instead of having a collection of SObject records). This is perhaps an alternate approach, but as is _it does not answer the question being asked_. I also get the feeling that using `event.target.checked` to set the state could have some unintended outcomes.

Comment: Separately, you should look through [the advanced editing help page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to learn how to better format your answers. Using triple back-ticks `\`\`\`` is all you needed here (that and removing unnecessary whitespace to keep your code looking neat and presentable). You can look at my edit to see what I changed.